# problems reating a new mezzanine (Author) page

Tags: django, python-2.7, mezzanine

im going throught the tutorial  of mezzanine

i create a new app using startapp and created an admin..py file

where i left this line"

```
admin.site.register(Author, PageAdmin)
```

in the models.py file i left these lines:

```
class Author(Page):
    dob = models.DateField("Date of birth")
class Book(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey("Author")
    cover = models.ImageField(upload_to="authors")
```

i cannot see the Author page in the website admin application

please help

Answer (score 1):

You created it as a Page so to see an author you would need to go to Content -> Pages and then click the dropdown that says Add...  One of the options in the dropdown should be author.